# How to quickly send the content of a text file to a mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, lua

#### Hi everyone!

I've made a MySQL database that contains the state of a minecraft lever using the ComputerCraft mod and some javascript but here is the problem : **it's too slow :/**
So I would like to know if there isn't a simpler / quicker way to do it **'\(*-*)/`**

---

Here are the steps I went through :
1-I've set a **computer** in my minecraft world with this **startup** program :

```lua
ecran = peripheral.find("monitor")
term.redirect(ecran)
while true do
    term.clear()
    local h = fs.open("test","w")
    print(os.version())
    print(rs.getInput("right"))
    text = "etatBout = '"..tostring(rs.getInput("right")).."'"
    h.write(text)
    h.close()
    os.sleep(0.5)
    term.setCursorPos(1,1)
end
```

so that the computer write the state of the lever in the file **'test'**
2-I've created a **index.html** file in the same folder :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TestMCJS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(etatBout)
        if(etatBout=='true'){
            window.open('http://192.168.1.47/minecraft/index.php?etatbouton=1', 'jeux');
        }else if(etatBout=='false'){
            window.open('http://192.168.1.47/minecraft/index.php?etatbouton=0', 'jeux');
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p></p>
</body>
```

so it send a php request to a lamp server I run on a **virtual machine** with the state of the button in parameter
3-I've created the **index.php** with the following code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $connexion = new mysqli("localhost","chuck","plouf","mc");
        $requete = $connexion->query("INSERT into `etatbouton` (etat) VALUES ('".$_GET['etatbouton']."')");
        $requete->close();
        $connexion->close();
    ?>
</body>
```

Then the state of the button is in my database in the **'etat'** column and is related to a **'date'** column with the **current_timestamp** as default value
4-Now I just have to **read** the database in **index2.php** :

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5"/>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $connexion = new mysqli("localhost","chuck","plouf","mc");
        $requete = $connexion->query("SELECT `etat` FROM `etatbouton` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $ligne = $requete->fetch_assoc();
        if($ligne['etat']!= 0){
            echo("<h1 style='font-size:5em;color:blue'>ON</h1>");
        }else{
            echo("<h1 style='font-size:5em;color:red'>OFF</h1>");
        }
        $requete->close();
        $connexion->close();
    ?>
</body>
```

And that's it.

---

I'm proud of me because I'm a **newbie** but I would like to know if there is a simpler or **quicker** way to do it because with this set I have to open **3** tabs and one is a **pop-up** so it is blocked by the browser and it takes approximetly **1 or 2 seconds** to update the button state in the browser **:/**

Comment: *"How to quickly send the content of a text file to a mysql database"* Check MySQL's [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) syntax -> *"The LOAD DATA statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed."*,

Comment: most likely you need to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL ... INTO TABLE ...` syntax -> *"If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started. "*

Comment: thank you two =)  I hadn't heard about this ^^

Comment: no problem  *"thank you two"* the last time i checked i still only was one person ;-) .. i had to make two separated comments otherwise it would not fit within the comment limit ..

Comment: oh yes xD so thank you one

Comment: *"I can't use LOAD DATA Because the ridden file has to be in the server folder. In my case the file is on my computer not on my server. "* notice i said `LOAD DATA LOCAL` -> *"If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server"*  But still -> *"if mysqld was started with the local_infile system variable disabled, LOCAL does not work"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi again**
Appenrently I could use `LOAD DATA` in my first page to avoid the pop-up and make it quicker so thank you.
Bye Bye **,(°0°)/**